# jquery change css class of 1 div with while you have multiple same names

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

The problem is,

I have 25 div's generating seats in a for each loop like this:]

```
 @foreach (Seats s in r.Seats) {
      if (s.IsOccupied == true) {
          <div id="@s.SeatNumber @r.RowNumber" class="seat   taken"><img src="~/Images/arm-chair.png" width="25" height="25" /></div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div id="@s.SeatNumber @r.RowNumber" class="seat free"><img src="~/Images/arm-chair.png" width="25" height="25" class="clickF" /></div>
                    }

                }
```

Then i want to change the background color of 1 div or multiple if you click on more, but when i do the background of all 25 change.

Is there a solution to this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".seat").click(function () {
        $(".seat").toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code $(this) is object of clicked div among $(".seat")

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".seat").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".seat").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

You need to refer to current div using `this` keyword.